# I need select rows by specification condition in part of one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a problem with a `SELECT` in SQL Server.
I need to select top 3 records of a table and after that I need find records with a condition in this 3 rows. I wrote this but result is incorrect.

```
SELECT TOP (3) * 
from data 
where state='c' 
order by time desc
```

My table (data) is like this:

```
code   data  state   time
 A1     12     n     2020/05/08 12:00
 A2     13     c     2020/05/08 11:59
 A3     10     n     2020/05/08 11:58
 A4     7      c     2020/05/08 11:57
 A5     18     e     2020/05/08 11:56
 A6     14     c     2020/05/08 11:55
```

I need result like this:

```
A2     13     c     2020/05/08 11:59
```

but my query result is :

```
 A2     13     c     2020/05/08 11:59
 A4     7      c     2020/05/08 11:57
 A6     14     c     2020/05/08 11:55
```

means I need find records by state='c' in top 3 rows NOT top 3 records of table that contain state='c'

I hope my explain is clear.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is with a CTE (common table expression) for the top 3 rows and then an outer query for the filter criteria:

```
WITH top3 AS (
    SELECT TOP (3) * 
    FROM data 
    ORDER BY time DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM top3
WHERE state='c';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Time DESC) AS [RowID]
    from data 
) DS
WHERE [RowID] <=3
    AND state = 'c'
```